# Botbuilder, multiple web sites with directline webcontrol. How to manage

Tags: botframework

We want to have multiple websites to place our chatbot to, but we would like to to use 1 bot middleware for sure, but inside we would like to track the origin, from which site the call is came from. I thought it is no brainer like configuring botconnection of js site like that:

```
var bot = {
        id:  'mysite1',
        name: 'mysite1'
    };
    BotChat.App({
        botConnection: botConnection,
        user: user,
        bot: bot
    }, document.getElementById("BotChatGoesHere"));
```

But I couldn't find "mysite1" anywhere in the flow on middleware, seems like bot service translate it to some guids anyway, so i explicitly add this mysite1 to pageLoad event that I also using to start chatbot interaction right away when user loads the page:

```
(function sendEvent() {
    botConnection
        .postActivity({ type: "event", value: "mysite1", from: { id: localStorage.getItem("guidJD"), name: localStorage.getItem("guidJD") }, name: "userLoadPage" })            
        .subscribe(id => console.log("success"));
})();
```

it working, but not stable, sometimes pageload event somehow fires after actual load of component and starting of dialog, so on start of dialog i didn't get needed for me origin info. Do you have any ideas how to fix that? or maybe i'm doing all wrong. Or should i add new site in Channels? Preferably we would like to do it by calling api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) implementation has been redesigned and is moving away from BotChat.app(). While it is still able to be used, best practice is to send to/receive from a bot using the WebChat.renderWebChat method.

To send the site location to a bot, add the following to your index.html page as a script. Please note, you shouldn't store your Direct Line secret in the browser or client app. It is included here only for simplicity.

In short, you are first creating a token by passing your Direct Line secret to the generate token API. Once the token is received, it is used to establish the Direct Line connection. The "window.WebChat.renderWebChat" method then renders the chat on the page. The location value is obtained when the page first loads and is then passed into the store's payload in the activity object under "channelData.location". Upon any "POST_ACTIVITY", the activity object is passed to the bot. There are a few other options you can choose from, such as "DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT" which will post the location when Direct Line first makes a connection.

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/simple-update-in/dist/simple-update-in.production.min.js'></script>
<script>
  (async function () {
    // To talk to your bot, you should use the token exchanged using your Direct Line secret.
    // You should never put the Direct Line secret in the browser or client app.
    const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + secret
      },
      json: true
    });
    const { token } = await res.json();

    cosnt location = window.location.href;

    let store = window.WebChat.createStore(
      {},
      ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
          // simple-update-in is used to update the "action"
          action = window.simpleUpdateIn(action, ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData', 'location'], () => location);
        }
        return next(action);
      }
    );

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
      store,
      styleOptions: {
        botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
        userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
      }
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
  })().catch(err => console.error(err));;
</script>
```

In the bot's activity object, we see the location value is passed in channelData, as we had specified.

```
channelData: { clientActivityID: '15469789226730.86rx9n6ssex', location: 'http://localhost:3000/' }
```

Hope of help!